# Is a file opened with newBufferedReader closed if an Exception occurs?

Tags: java, file, exception, memory-leaks, bufferedreader

I usually open files by fetching a BufferedReader:

```
Files.newBufferedReader(myPath).lines()
    .doStuff()
    .doMoreStuff();
```

What happens when the method throws an Exception, will the Reader be closed automatically like with a try-with-resource? I found no reference in the docs.

Comment: No, I dont think so. That is why its suggested to use try-with-resource or atleast try-cacth-finally construct.

Comment: I just can't see the advantage of using the factory method instead of simply creating a new BufferedReader. I thought this way it would be more concise, but having to wrap it with exception handling makes it no different from standard initialisation.

Answer (score 3):

The `Files.newBufferedReader` is just a utility/factory method to create a `BufferedReader` for the File. Internally it eventually does a `new BufferedReader()` to create the BufferedReader.

So, you would have to treat it the same way as you would create the BufferedReader using the `new` operator. If you want it to be auto-closed at the end of the try block, you would have to use the `try-with-resource` as you would, if you had to create it using the `new` operator.

Comment: Hmm I see, but a try-with-resource would look really ugly in that case I guess since it's a stream and I would have to include the whole stream inside of the try-with-clause?